# Why am I able to open this file?

Tags: files, access-control

While debugging a USB device usage I've come across a puzzling behavior of `open(2)`:

```
admin@anahata-core-i5:/tmp$ groups
admin sudo
admin@anahata-core-i5:/tmp$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/051
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 189, 50 Jun 19 20:03 /dev/bus/usb/001/051
admin@anahata-core-i5:/tmp$ cat test.c 
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    return open("/dev/bus/usb/001/051",O_RDWR);
}
admin@anahata-core-i5:/tmp$ gcc test.c -o test && ./test ; echo $?
3
```

As you can see in the above session log, despite `/dev/bus/usb/001/051` being accessible only to user `root` and group `audio`, I still successfully `open` the file for reading and writing.

What's going on? Why don't I get `EPERM`?

**EDIT** in response to comment:

```
admin@anahata-core-i5:/tmp$ getfacl  /dev/bus/usb/001/051
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/051
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:admin:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/051`. The `+` in the permissions means there are extra permissions in place.

Comment: @terdon edited. Though now I see what happens...

Comment: Yup, that's the idea :) Why don't you post the `getfacl` command and the conclusion you draw from it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` in mode output of `ls -l` (`crw-rw----+`) means that ACLs are being used. The output of `getfacl  /dev/bus/usb/001/051` in the OP contains one particular line:

```
user:admin:rw-
```

This means that, in addition to other permission settings, user `admin` is granted read and write permission for this file.

Comment: `/dev` should be populated by Udev. Did you change it yourself?

Comment: @heemayl Nope, it's the default in Kbuntu 14.04 for my Samsung Galaxy Tab unless I have X started and active (and also in X when KDE is running).